# Set property in page view model depending on state of client view model in Durandal

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, durandal

The page is bound to page view model and inside page I load a client view bounded to it's own view model. I try to keep things separate so page view model knows only the name of client view and does not communicate with client view model directly. So page view looks like:

```
<div>
    <div data-bind="compose:client"></div> <!-- client is an observable of type string -->
</div>
<!-- some more bindings -->
```

But I need to update some properties on page view model depending on state of client view model because those properties are bound to page view (not to client view). What's the best way to do it? Should I use `app.triger` in client view model and listen in page view model? Would be better to just bind to client view models (`client` property of page view model would be an object or function instead of string) and communicate with current client view model directly from page view model through common interface to get state of client view model and compute some propertes on page view model? What are best practices there?

Also I would try to avoid using `preserveContext:true` as this seem to be least clean option.

I'm not using routing if that matters because routing would not be useful on that page. I'm changing `client` property manually from page view model.

I'm on Durandal 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pub/sub seems to be the best way to go as you've indicated that the view models should be separated. Instead of using app for communication you might consider creating a small module that is shared between clients/page

```
define(['durandal/events'],function(Events) {
    var myObj = { ... };
    Events.includeIn(myObj);


    return myObj;
});
```

If you later decide that you want some tighter coupling you can add some shared observable to myObj as well.